# SSG NextJS on Gitlab Pages stucked on 404?

Tags: gitlab, next.js

I started a simple SSG NextJS project to build my personal website/portfolio: https://gitlab.com/soykje/soykje.gitlab.io, that I want to deploy using Gitlab pages (but without the `now` stuff...).

I created the `.gitlab-ci.yml` and updated the `next.config.js` to take care of `assetPrefix` parameter, but still I'm getting a mysterious 404. And I can't find a way to fix it, as the CI/CD tells everything is fine... :(

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: node

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules

before_script:
  - npm install

pages:
  script:
    - npm run publish # eq. to "next build && next export"
    - mv out public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

Did anyone encounter the same issue deploying a static NextJS project using Gitlab Pages? Any help would be great, thx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found the reason: I was not using the `mv` command properly... So finally I ended up with the following config, and everything runs fine:

```
image: node

before_script:
  - npm install

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules

pages:
  script:
    - npm run publish
    - mv out/* public
    - rm -rf out
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

Hope that will help!

Comment: I used this instruction and it ran
pages:
  script:
    - npm run-script build && npm run-script export
    - rm -rf public/*
    - mv out/* public

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab CI allows to override the default published directory (`public`) to another value.

This can be achieved with the `pages:publish` keyword as mentionned in the official documentation :

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#pagespublish

That way, `mv` is not needed anymore and `.gitlab-ci.yml` could look like :

```yaml
image: node

before_script:
  - npm install

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules

pages:
  script:
    - npm run publish
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - out
  publish: out
  only:
    - master
```